# Citing the Jerusalem Talmud and Mishna Torah

Tags: rambam, how-to, talmud-yerushalmi

How would you write an academic citation (format agnostic) for the Jerusalem Talmud or the Mishna Torah? i.e. a specific quote from each. I'm specifically asking about these as there is no standard printing.

Comment: See: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7171/citation-format-for-gmara

Comment: Edited as requested. The linked page mentions the Bavli but I'm asking specifically about Yerushalmi and MT because there is no standard printing.

Comment: The edit, now makes this question appear as an academic format question rather than a Judaic question. Comments?

Comment: @Yishai That seems like a dupe. It doesn't only mention Bavli.

Comment: @DanF, I think the decision at the time of [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44455/academic-abbreviations) was that such a question is on topic. I was on the other side of that debate, FWIW.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't know, what is the policy about a question that is more narrow than the original? On the one hand the original covers it, on the other hand the original invites good answers to simply ignore the detail sought here.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I agree that the Jerusalem Talmud part of this question duplicates that question. In fact, the particular issue that marisbest2 highlighted in a comment above - that of no standard printing - is addressed by the primary answer: Note the edition. I recommend refocusing this question to apply specifically to MT.

Comment: @IsaacMoses It also asks about various commentaries.

Comment: @DoubleAA "... whose comments appear in the back of the same volume." MT is not a commentary, and it certainly doesn't appear in the back of Talmud volumes.

Comment: @IsaacMoses The please just edit in an "etc." as that's what the answerers took it to mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23665/discussion-between-isaac-moses-and-double-aa).

Comment: @Yishai I'm not sure exaclty what your case is but you may find this helpful http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3507/759

Comment: @marisbest2 Please note Isaac's comment above and [edit] out the duplicate parts of this question. Be sure to clarify what exactly you want to know that isn't addressed there and why it isn't covered there.

Comment: I thought I did that with "I'm specifically asking about these as there is no standard printing." The linked answer doesn't address MT or YT as far as I can tell, other than to say its the same as the bible.